# Should general secret hats questions only be asked on SE Meta

Tags: discussion, migration, winter-bash-2014

I saw this question in Meta Arqade:

> [How did I get a secret hat?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10143/how-did-i-get-a-secret-hat)

Should it be asked on Meta Stack Exchange, instead of just Meta Arqade, a not-so-important-and-popular Meta? As the question is generally about all sites in Stack Exchange, not just about Arqade. You see, the instructions of "ask a question" says:

> If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

It says **this website**, which means the questions should be only about the site Arqade, but this question is about the whole Stack Exchange site, not just Arqade.

So, the general question: "Should questions about WB14 Hatz be moved to Meta Stack Exchange??"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Asking about hats is still asking about "this website" because the site has hats. Each site is encompassed within the scope of *all* sites, so a lot of topics will be relevant on both Metas. That doesn't mean, though, that we should be analyzing each question for whether or not it would be relevant to all sites on the network and should be migrated to the network Meta.

As an example, Meta Stack Overflow has [27 questions about the Winterbash](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) that would really achieve nothing by being migrated.

It is generally acceptable to ask any of your questions on the child Meta, and moderators will migrate over anything that truly does need to be on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: True. From what I have seen over the months since the split, only Careers questions get migrated from MSO into MSE.

Comment: Yup, I agree. There's nothing special about hats with regard to where to ask questions. They falls under our usual rules: child metas are any individual user's home, though mods may choose to migrate if necessary.